# How to make mysql interpret a field as string in LOAD DATA

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a insert to mysql from a csv file which has 100+ rows. In which there's a **description** field, so there is *commas* in that field and possibly *enters*.

I'm running this command below to up the sheet to the database, however whenever it finds a comma it skips to the next field, so it fills the field with the wrong data

```
LOAD DATA infile 'objeto.csv'
INTO TABLE objeto
fields terminated BY ","
lines terminated BY "\n"
```

Here's an example of one of the descriptions:

> Explora la presión por encima y debajo del agua. Ve cómo cambia la
>   presión a medida que cambias los fluidos, la gravedad, la forma del
>   contenedor, y el volumen

I've tried to change from "," to "/" or "-" but it either still filled wrong or with NULL

So, the other fix I've got in mind is trying to make it see the whole field as a string maybe. But I'm not sure if that's even possible...

I just could not find any fix so far.

Comment: If there are delimiters (in this case, a comma) within columns then those data values need to be quoted, and you need to use a clause like `columns optionally enclosed by '"'`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the quoted solve, sorry for not including it in the post. However, as I mentioned, there is 100+ descriptions, so if this is the only way I guess I'll have to get to work, but isn't there any work around?? :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simple work around that might help anyone with this sort of problem. I started messing with the csv file instead of trying to find an SQL fix or something.
I acutally did a pretty simply fix, went in sheets and made the field separator be ";" instead of "," and also I have to change all of the semicolons that were in the file before doing so.

So, if anyone run into this, I try fixing it with a work around messing with the csv file, might help ;)